# javascript regex -What can I do in my case?

Tags: javascript, regex

what I would like to do is-

```
var t = "search value"
```

regular expression is -

```
[\,,\s]t[\,,\s]+
```

How can I put it in here-

```
var re = new RegExp(t, 'g');
```

Comment: lots of examples if you google this https://www.google.com.pe/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=javascript+regular+expression

Comment: yes I looked in google but for some reason I couldnt do it :( ....

Comment: Then show what error you get

Comment: I tried this-
`RegExp("\\[\,\,\\s]"+t+"\\[\,\,\\s\\]+", 'g');` And it did not work.

Comment: `RegExp("[,\\s]"+t+"[,\\s]+", 'g')` should work - why were you escaping the brackets, making them literal characters? Also, no need to escape the commas or put them into the character class twice.

Comment: Be aware that this regex will not match `t` if it's at the very start or end of a string, and that it may fail in unexpected ways if `t` itself contains regex metacharacters. There may be a better way of doing what you're doing - you haven't really explained what your regex is supposed to do exactly.

Comment: nope it does not work @TimPietzcker ... I just dont know why this is not working...

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) together with your expected and actual results. "It doesn't work" isn't precise enough.

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

You have passed `t` as the first parameter. It should not be the search value, but the `pattern`

**According to the documentation**

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

```
new RegExp(pattern[, flags])
```

**pattern**

The text of the regular expression.

**flags**
If specified, flags can have any combination of the following values:

`g` - global match

`i` - ignore case

`m` - multiline; treat beginning and end characters (^ and $) as working over multiple lines (i.e., match the beginning or end of each line (delimited by \n or \r), not only the very beginning or end of the whole input string)

`y` - sticky; matches only from the index indicated by the lastIndex property of this regular expression in the target string (and does not attempt to match from any later indexes).

Comment: `t` *is* supposed to be part of the pattern.